# postgresql query returning in random order

Tags: javascript, sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to create a SQL query that queries a database and returns info on various airports.

The basic query works fine, however the results are returned in a random order.

```
SELECT * FROM airportdata WHERE airportcode LIKE 'LHR' OR airportcode LIKE 'HKG'
```

It is really important that they are returned in the order passed into the query (i.e. the airport data from LHR be the first result returned followed by the airport info for HKG), however I can't get find any ORDER BY that will work.

apparently FIND_IN_SET is what I should be using, however I've tried all variations and I can't get it to work!

```
SELECT * FROM airportdata WHERE airportcode LIKE 'LHR' OR airportcode LIKE 'HKG' ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(airportcode,'LHR,HKG')
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps with a CASE statement to build a sorting key?

Comment: "returned in the order passed into the query" — what does that mean?

Comment: I've amended to clarify what I mean! Cheers

Comment: And why are you using `LIKE` without any real pattern? Why isn't it just `=`?

Comment: So `order by airportcode desc` ?

Comment: I'm using like as sometimes the input is passed in as lowercase by the user, I can't change this! I just simplified the query to try and make my problem clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM airportdata 
WHERE airportcode LIKE 'LHR' OR airportcode LIKE 'HKG' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN airportcode LIKE 'LHR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use `IN`.  You can then use a

```
SELECT *
FROM airportdata
WHERE airportcode IN ('LHR', 'HKG')
ORDER BY position(airportcode in 'LHR,HKG')
```

(This is safe because airport codes should be 3 characters and not have commas.)

If you want to use `LIKE` (which supports wildcards), you 
can do:

```
SELECT ad.*
FROM airportdata ad JOIN
     (VALUES ('LHR', 1),
             ('HKG', 2)
     ) v(pattern, pos)
     ON v.airportcode LIKE pattern
ORDER BY pos;
```

This does run the risk of duplicates, because one code could (theoretically) match multiple patterns.  If that is a real risk, you would need to explain which pattern you prefer.